# adding values to array inside codeigniter session

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, session

i'm trying to create a session in codeigniter by setting an array i can set the array but when i try to input another array it overwrites the first array

```
   <?php
    $array = array(
    'delivery_address' => array(
    'house_name' => $house_name,
    'address1' => $address1,
    'address2' => $address2,
    'city' => $city,
    'county' => $county,
    'country'=> $country,
    'postcode' => $postcode

     )

     );
     $this->session->userdata($array);
     $result = $this->session->userdata('delivery_address');
     print_r($result);
     ?>
```

i guess what i'm looking for is that when i go back to set another array with

```
      $array = array('delivery_address'=>array(
        )

     );
```

that it has multiple values i can loop through 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('delivery_address'=>array( ));
```

will always be overwritten you need

```
$array[] = array('delivery_address'=>array( ));
```

This will add

> array('delivery_address'=>array( )

as a new elememt in the first array.

Comment: when i use the $array[] iget this error when using print_r                 Severity: Notice

Message: Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:

Comment: what happens if you change '$result = $this->session->userdata('delivery_address');' to  '$result = $this->session->userdata();'

Comment: when i print_r ($this->session->userdata()); it displays the full session  including all the delivery address's i put in the session but when i just put $this-.session->userdata('delivery_address'); it only displays the first delivery address  and nothing else  i tried looping through the result  and print_r it but it looked liked it just appended the whole session together strange :)

Comment: ok try  `$array['delivery_addresses'][ ] = array('delivery_address'=>array( ));` then  `$result = $this->session->userdata('delivery_addresses');`

Comment: this way just also only shows the first address put into the session   again when i put the $this->session->userdata(); it displays all the addresses saved along with all other session data :(

Comment: You're definitely using `$result = $this->session->userdata('delivery_addresses');`  ? This should be another array with all the address arrays inside.

Answer (score 0):

**Assume this is your array**

```
$array = array(
    'delivery_address' => array(
        'house_name' => 'aa',
        'address1' => 'bbb',
        'address2' => 'ccc'
    )
);
```

---

```
$array['delivery_address']['house_name'] = 'new Value';
print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
Array ( 
    [delivery_address] => Array ( 
        [house_name] => new Value 
        [address1] => bbb 
        [address2] => ccc ) 
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead create sessions like this:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session1', array1());
```

this will preserve the first session you created.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('session2', array2());
```

then call your sessions like :

```
$session1 = $this->session->userdata('session1');
$session2 = $this->session->userdata('session2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    **I had a similar problem way back but I just had to enter 5 arrays in session
    Codeigniter overrides the array if there is an array already in session so I came up
 with this little Nasty Code but it works 100% but it has limitations **


      if($this->session->userdata('delivery_address1')==false) {
                $this->session->set_userdata('delivery_address1', $array);
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('delivery_address1')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address2')==false){
                $this->session->set_userdata('delivery_address2', $array);
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('delivery_address1')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address2')==true && $this->session->userdata('cart_delivery_address')==false){
                $this->session->set_userdata('delivery_address3', $array);
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('delivery_address1')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address2')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address3')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address4')==false){
                $this->session->set_userdata('delivery_address4', $array);
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('delivery_address1')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address2')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address3')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address4')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address5')==false){
                $this->session->set_userdata('delivery_address5', $array);
            }
            elseif($this->session->userdata('delivery_address1')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address2')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address3')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address4')==true && $this->session->userdata('delivery_address5')==true) {
                //do something here

            }
```